# Azure VPN for all users via Add-VPNConnection CmdLets script - EapConfigXmlStream error

Tags: powershell, vpn, powershell-cmdlet

I need to create a VPN that all users on a Windows 2012 machine can use.

I followed [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28745579/Windows-10-VPN-connection-setup-allow-other-people-to-use-this-connection-not-working-Network-Sign-in-not-showing-on-logon-screen.html) link and now I am trying this:

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name MY_VPN_NAME -ServerAddress azuregateway-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx.cloudapp.net
 -AllUserConnection $true -UseWinLogonCredential $true 
-RememberCredential $true -TunnelType Automatic -EncryptionLevel Required -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2
```

But keeping getting this error:

```
Add-VpnConnection : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'EapConfigXmlStream'. Cannot convert value
"True" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this
node, because the specified node is the wrong type."
At line:1 char:202
+ ... mberCredential $true -TunnelType Automatic -EncryptionLevel Required -Authentica ...
+                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-VpnConnection], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationExcep
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-VpnConnection
```

How can I change the script in order to create the VPN please

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the value $true from the -AllUserConnection -UseWinlogoncredential and -RememberCredential parameters it will work. Simply specifying these parameters is what enables them (makes them true).

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name MY_VPN_NAME -ServerAddress azuregateway-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx.cloudapp.net -AllUserConnection -UseWinLogonCredential -RememberCredential -TunnelType Automatic -EncryptionLevel Required -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2
```

Don't forget because you are using the -AllUserConnection parameter you will need to run PowerShell as an Administrator.

Also it's a good idea to put quotes around your strings, not that it will matter in this example.

```
Add-VpnConnection -Name "MY_VPN_NAME" -ServerAddress "azuregateway-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx.cloudapp.net" -AllUserConnection -UseWinLogonCredential -RememberCredential -TunnelType "Automatic" -EncryptionLevel "Required" -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2
```

Take a look at the examples (not just the syntax) for Add-VpnConnection on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554824.aspx it makes the usage a bit clearer.